# Leave Header Blank Fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, r, rmarkdown

I am new to coding and Latex so please forgive me as I'm sure this is a very straight forward solution. I am creating a PDF report using RMarkdown with a .tex file to control the header, margins, and page type.

I have managed to create a base header that I will continue to tweak more to my liking but I need to be able to turn the header off for the 2nd page of the report and then turn it back on for the 3rd page. I have a `flextable` that is too large with the header to fit on the 2nd page but fits without it.

I have read many questions where they are asking about the 1st page but I haven't been able to tweak those answers to solve my problem. I have read the fancyhdr vignette and I'm sure the answer is in there but everything I tried did not work. Most turned the header off on the first page and didn't touch the second. Do I need to put the code directly into the .rmd?

YAML header for my RMarkdown file:

```
---
title: "Team Report"
classoption: landscape
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"

---
```

preamble.tex file

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{geometry}

 \geometry{a4paper, landscape, left = 13mm, right = 5mm, top = 5mm, bottom = 13mm, head = 44pt, includeheadfoot}
  \headsep = 2mm



\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{210, 35, 42}
\fancyhead[L]{\colorbox{col1}{{\color{white}{\large\textbf{July 2020}}}}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\Huge\textbf{Team Report Template}}
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{Team_logo.png}} % right logo
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{4pt}
```

Answer (score 1):

R markdown can use LaTeX commands directly, so simply add `\thispagestyle{empty}` in the second page.

The command just before or after the R chunk could be enough, but to be sure will be not load before the first page break nor after the second page break, place it just before a `\newpage`:  I

````
---
title: "Team Report"
classoption: landscape
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "preamble.tex"

---

(first page contents)

\newpage 
\thispagestyle{empty}


 
```{r}
# R chunk of the second page 
```
````

Alternatively, you can also load the `afterpage` package and place `\afterpage{\thispagestyle{empty}}`  somewhere in the first page.